Keycloak 25.0.2 - Django - Force Login
I need to add an external auth in my Django + Keycloak application.
Unfortunally there is no native plugin for this auth (is specific for my Country) so I need to manage it with Python and then force a user login using PythonKeycloack (that use api) without knowing the user password.
What I have is an admin account, and relative tokens, that may be usefull to achieve this goal.
Thanks


Can you use mozilla-django-oidc? Keycloack uses oidc as protocol: https://phasetwo.io/blog/secure-django/

Is this plugin allow me to log user without knowing his password?

yes, you forward the request to the keycloack server, that shows the page to log in, and when that is successful, passes an ecrypted token back to Django that will make a corresponding user (without password) at the Django site.

But I cant use the Keycloak login. I need to completely avoid that part.
For Example, I open a Google Account Login with Django. When Google return to Django with a trusted user, I need to log it on Keycloak without knowing his password but using only admin super power
